# Auto resize images after adding a new size

Tags: images

I have added a new (small) image size to the theme we develop:

`add_image_size('small', 160, 91, TRUE);`

How to automatically generate these small images (exactly of the specified size) for every image uploaded in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress doesn't regenerate the newly registered size, only applies it to future uploads.

You'll have to use something like the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin or one of the similar ones available at WordPress.org.

Comment: Regenerate Thumbnails plugin seems not to create images of my custom size (see my question for exact specification of the size I need). So it isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Hm, now it works. Probably I should have press Ctrl+F5.

Comment: That does help. ;)